# Email validation without plugin

Tags: jquery

I am implementing email validation without any plugins. To that end, I've written this validation code:

```
var email = encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());

if(email==='' | email=== null) {
    $('#erroremail').show();
} else {
    var checkemail = email;
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    if(filter.test(checkemail)) {
        alert('Correct');
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Not Correct');
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I never get the correct alert. What's not working?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: [Regeeeeeeex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)! On a serious note, check your regex in [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) (or similar) to make sure it validates as you want it to. Also, I'm really not sure why you're `.test()`ing the string you want to validate _against_. Try reading some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript).

Comment: Another email regex, another poor, dead kitten

Comment: you should add another | on your if statement and encodeURIComponent will transform @ to %40 so it will never get a validate. is there a reason you need to use encodeURICompontent?

Answer (score 0):

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/mw69d/2/
your regex works with a simple mail, so the problem must be the encodeURIComponent function that modifies the $('#email').val().